# How can I re-launch a mobile app (its background services) after user reboots the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've found some answers for past versions of iOS, but I can't find a real answer to launch an app after user reboots the device.

I'm not trying to launch the app itself to foreground, but the service registered in background to be alive again after rebooting.

Comment: Why is it that you think WhatsApp is restarting after the phone reboots?

Comment: Because, if you reboot the mobile and do not touch anything, and receive a Whatsapp message, it appears a notification

Comment: That's a push notification. You can receive push notifications from a server even if the app isn't running. When the user taps on the notification, the os will start the app.

Comment: Well, but the question is about background services

Comment: Okay then. Ask the question you really want to know the answer to. You can't re-launch a mobile app after the user reboots the phone.

Comment: edited ... thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "background service"?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated - did you tried?